# Truffle re-deploy unchanged contracts on every migrate

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

On every `truffle migrate` truffle deploy contracts even if they are not changed.
although it doesn't re-compile

Truffle v5.0.5

Comment: Perhaps are you on windows? Sometimes truffle is confused by some artifacts it had created in build/ directory. Usually removing build/ directory will eliminate any bad artifact and force truffle to re-compile all contracts, some alternative commands: `truffle compile --all` (force contract recompilation, but it will not remove unrecognized artifacts) and `truffle migrate --reset` (force contracts redeployment).

Answer (score 0):

Solved by updating truffle

```
npm uninstall -g truffle
npm install -g truffle
```